# Zoom - Output both headset audio and microphone output to Zoom call

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, zoom-meeting

Windows 10
Steelseries Arctis 7 headset

Working over Zoom, and wish to share what I hear in my headphones along with my microphone output with other participants in the call.

I tried following the recipe in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1670875/broadcast-desktop-audio-mic-via-obs-or-other-to-zoom-or-discord), by installing vb-audio cable, but was unable to get all audio going to the Zoom call together.
I could get my microphone outputting to the Zoom call, OR my headphone audio (without my mic) outputting to the Zoom call, but was unable to get all sources going to Zoom together.

I even tried using OBS as a go-between, but was unable to achieve the desired result.

Is there a known solution/recipe to do this?

References:

https://vb-audio.com/Cable/

[Broadcast desktop audio + mic (via OBS or other) to Zoom or Discord](https://superuser.com/questions/1670875/broadcast-desktop-audio-mic-via-obs-or-other-to-zoom-or-discord)

Comment: Share Screen has a share sound checkbox as [1NN answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1737957/160219) indicates, were you looking for a solution that doesn't involve sharing your screen? A seemingly simple solution would have you attach a 3.5mm Y splitter to your microphone jack, plug in your mic to one spot, use an aux cord from PC speaker output jack to the other part of the Y splitter. This & SW solutions will likely create a feedback loop that is why people can't do this easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Zoom, go to `share screen -> Advanced -> Desktop audio`, and click on the `share` button. This will share any audio you can hear over your headphones, except the voices of other participants in the zoom call.
[read complete tutorial with images](https://tuftsedtech.screenstepslive.com/s/19028/m/94934/l/1379926-how-do-i-share-audio-only-without-sharing-my-screen), or [see the Zoom help page](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362643-Sharing-computer-sound-in-a-screen-share)

If you need to show images, too, you'll need to share your desktop, or in the `advanced` tab select `portion of screen`. Then make sure the `share audio` checkbox is ticked before clicking on the `share` buttton.

In the end, make sure your mic is on in Zoom, so others can hear your voice.

### EDIT

1. Note that when sharing sound, default is "mono", but you can choose "Stereo" from the drop-down menu next to the sharing option.
2. Zoom will apply various filters to any audio. That's why the OBS / audio-cable won't work: Zoom will filter out any music or anything it classifies as "noise" from the mic. However, there's a way to transmit exactly the input audio: In `Settings -> Audio`, enable the `Show in-meeting option to enable "Original Sound"`. Then, during the meeting, you'll find at the top left a button to switch to `Original Sound`. Doing this, you might be able to use the virtual audio-cable, if for any reason you prefer to do it that way.

Comment: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362643-Sharing-computer-sound-in-a-screen-share

Comment: Thanks, @gregg , I've edited it in

Comment: Game, set and match - thanks 1NN